# Show first frame of video in WPF MediaElement

Tags: .net, wpf, video, mediaelement

I have a WPF-application with a MediaElement which I use to run a video. I don't want the video to autoplay when loaded, so I set the LoadedBehavior to Manual.

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
              Source="foo.wmv" 
              MediaOpened="videoElement_MediaOpened" />
```

However; I want the element to show the first frame of the video when loaded. Is there any magic way of doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You also need

```
ScrubbingEnabled="True"
```

Then set an event on Load

```
Loaded="Video1_Loaded"
```

In the Video1_Load method add the following:

```
Video1.Play();
Video1.Pause();
```

None of the video content is rendered before the play method is called. So even if you set the position past the first frame you won't get any data rendered.

I think the [MediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.scrubbingenabled.aspx) Property is the key.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates
>   whether the MediaElement will update
>   frames for seek operations while
>   paused. This is a dependency property.

I tried the same approach without `ScrubbingEnabled` but found that the first frame wouldn't render. Not sure if it's just the hardware I am using for this. The other item to remember is that the way the MediaElement works, once you call `Play()` you may not actually `Pause()` on the first frame exactly, so you may want to reduce the volume on the stream before calling `Play()` and reset after calling `Pause()`.

Comment: Thx - this works! I must say I'm not all comfortable with the Play() Pause() trigging. Saw someone else suggesting it too, but found the approach a bit "hacky". But if this is the only way I guess we'll have to live with it. ScrubbingEnabled is a nice property, but doesn't seem to have anything to do with showing the first video frame on startup.

Comment: Using the `MediaOpened` event instead of `Loaded` works for me, as long as I play then pause in the event handler.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to create an event, see following

```
<MediaElement Source="foo.wmv" 
              MediaOpened="videoElement_MediaOpened" 
              LoadedBehavior="Pause" ScrubbingEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: you can't controls the MediaElement with play, stop ... So you must set LoadedBehavior to manual. if you set it to pause how would you start it to play?

Comment: @AlexanderZwitbaum: By calling the `Play` method based on some other event, unrelated to the integrated buttons?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, so here is my answer:
Scrubbing refers to updating the rendered image when the MediaElement is paused.

```
//Todo: Set your source

//if not stated in the xmal, you can still set this here.
Player.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

//Turn scrubbing on
Player.ScrubbingEnabled = true;

Player.Pause();

Player.Position = TimeSpan.FromTicks(1);
```

Thanks for the scrubbing tip!