# WPF MediaElement. Play not from beginning

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I can't achieve simple thing. I'm using MediaElement and I want to play my video not from the beginning, but from, let's say, position 5 sec.

Workflow:

```
LoadedBehavior <- Manual;
Source <- some_source;
Play();
```

Inside MediaOpened:

```
Position <- 5 sec
```

Problem: For the few moments I see the beginning of the video and then it switches to 5 sec.
I know that if I want to control Position manually I need to use LoadedBehavior Manual, but how can I make the video be Paused immediately after loading?

Comment: as a workaround hide the media element initially, and show when it starts playing from the desired time

Comment: I have a fadeIn() method where I animate OpacityProprerty and VolumeProperty from 0 to 1. And I do that inside MediaOpened event handler AFTER I set desired position and I still notice the skip between positions.

Comment: perhaps adjust a begin time of animation with few hundred ms to see if that helps. see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346886/show-first-frame-of-video-in-wpf-mediaelement?rq=1) helps too

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it and works is this (_location & _position I want are passed into the containing method of course)

```
MediaE2.Source = _location;
MediaE2.Position = _position;
//MediaE2.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv", UriKind.Absolute);

MediaE2.Play();
```

Set the position first then play.

Jim

Comment: No, I can't set Position before MediaOpened event fire, because media attributes are not defined yet.

Comment: gs_vlad,  Can you give us a little more info or code so we can try and help further.